# cakephp validation problem: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, cakephp

I am just starting on cakePHP and I came across this problem

`Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2611]`

I get that when I try and add/edit a post. It's getting triggered by this validation code:

```
var $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'title_not_blank' => array(
                'rule' => 'nonEmpty',
                'message' => 'This post is missing a title'
            ),
            'title_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'A post with this title already exists'
            )
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'body_not_blank' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Post is missing its body'
            )
        )
    );
```

I have no idea what to do? Any help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You know what? You are doing validation rules/code correctly (even with multiple rules per field). The only cause of your problem is that you are writing nonEmpty instead of notEmpty (notice the **t**) in you first rule.

Yeah, I know how frustrating these minor things can be. Perhaps this is why we coders eventually develop OCD. :D

Comment: Don't forget 'notEmpty' is deprecated - use 'notBlank' instead.

Comment: It can also happen if you use a valid rule (e.g. `notBlank`) in an older version of CakePHP where it didn't exist yet.